# Drawer with ListViewBuilder and Header in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I'm trying to make a drawer widget that uses a `ListViewBuilder` to populate itself based on a list injected into the `ViewModel`.

However, I'm having issues getting it to play ball.

I've wrapped the LVB in a `SizedBox` to provide it with vertical bounds (since it was throwing a bunch of errors, as suggeested by another answer, and that's stopped those, but now I'm getting an overflow.

The header also doesn't fill out the width anymore either.

```dart
class MainDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<MainDrawerViewModel>(builder: (context, model, child) {
      return Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            DrawerHeader(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: ThemeColors.primaryDark),
              child: Text(S.current.drawerTitle, style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30)),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: double.maxFinite,
              child: ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    itemCount: model.mainDrawerItems.length,
                    itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                      final drawerItem = model.mainDrawerItems[index];
                      return ListTile(
                        leading: drawerItem.icon,
                        title: Text(drawerItem.title, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
                        selected: model.currentScreen == drawerItem.screen,
                        selectedTileColor: ThemeColors.selectedDrawerItem,
                        onTap: () {
                          model.selectScreen(drawerItem.screen);
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                      );
                    }),
            ),
          ],
        ));
    });
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of problem]

This feels like something that should be pretty easy... What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Expanded` widget on listView instead of  `height: double.maxFinite,`

```dart
Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
```

`double.maxFinite = 1.7976931348623157e+308;` and it is equal to `1.7976931348623157 × 10^308` which is too big. and the overflow happens.

For header, you can wrap With `SizedBox` and provide  `width: double.maxFinite,`. Also you can just use a container with decoration like

```dart
class MainDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
        child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: double.maxFinite,
          height: 200, // based on your need
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amber),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 16),
          child: Text(
            "S.cu ",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: ui.Color.fromARGB(255, 203, 19, 19),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 30),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              itemCount: 3,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.abc_outlined),
                  title: Text("drawerItem.title",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
                  selected: true,
                  onTap: () {},
                );
              }),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, that fixes the overflow, thank you... What about the header though?

Comment: You like to fill the header width?